# What can I do to clarify what I'm asking?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [solving a biot savart problem to completion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/445766/solving-a-biot-savart-problem-to-completion)

I'm gonna be honest, this seems like a classic "close because of miscellaneous reason not related to what I voted for" that is seen across stack exchange, but I'm going to nonetheless ask: What can I do to clarify my question to make it more clearly state the question?

Answer (score 4):

Your question was closed because... well...it is unclear.

1. You do not specify what $r$ is and instead you expect the  readers to divine it for you.  To be specific how can you expect someone who was not present at the lecture to

> provide some context about how you would find $\hat r$ and $r$?

2. What is the problem here?  Is it the integration?
3. You claim

   > For the most part, it's just a big QED, because it's calculus, not electromagnetism.

I don’t understand what that means.  You have an integral to evaluate hence it *is* a calculus problem.

4. What do you mean by QED?  *Quid est demonstratum* (which I presume must be right) or quantum electrodynamics?
5. What are $X$, $Y$ and $Z$?

To be blunt this is a simple example, and this or similar are found in many textbooks.  Did you consult any of them?

Comment: i don't think toy read the question.  the problem is posed right before the examples...

Comment: would it help if i posted the standard form of biot savart?

Comment: see items 1,2,3,4 and 5 of my answer.  You might consider to those as initial fixes, and compare with any other textbook example.

Comment: i did.. you say  there's no problem,  it's posted right there.

Comment: I don’t see you addressing any of the items above...  It’s your question that was closed... 5 people agreed it was unclear: you can either fix it or not.

Comment: 2: "how could one solve this using Biot-Savart law to end up with a function  for the magnetic field in terms of a point  and constants due to the current in the wire?"

Comment: is that not satisfactory? why not?

Comment: of course the field is a function of the current and of a point... you are calculating the field *at one point* due to *a current*... or do you think the field is uniform (which it is not)?  Don’t take this the wrong way but find examples in other textbooks.  What is $X$, $Y$, $Z$?

Comment: it's the cartesian coordinates from the coordinates system? how do imake that clear?

Comment: i’ve said enough.

Comment: i agree. this isn't useful.